# Minimize more than one variable

Tags: linear-programming, cplex

My model starts off like that:

```
Minimize
 +T

\* Constraints *\
Subject To
 +T -Ta >= 0 //T >= Ta
 +T -Tb >= 0 //T >= Tb
 +T -Tc >= 0 //and so on
 +T -Td >= 0
 +T -Te >= 0
```

The `Tx` variables are only lower-bounded, with no upper bound. What happens is that CPLEX correctly identifies the critical variable, but all the other ones end up "stretched" - for example, when `Ta >= 1000`, and `Tb >= 10`, `Tb` will also be 1000.

I want to tell the solver "Minimize `T`, and also minimize all the `Tx` variables, but only if it doesn't impact `T` negatively". How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem as formulated is degenerate (in the sense that variables can take on multiple values and still be optimal). You can perturb that by adding more terms to the Objective Function, without changing the desired solution effect.

One way to do that is to include the other variables (your Tx variables) also in the Objective Function.

For example, you could make your Obj to be:

```
Minimize T + Ta + Tb + Tc + Td + Te
```

This will not adversely impact the value of your main `T` variable.

More commonly, the convention is to do something like:

```
Minimize
     T + epsilon(Ta + Tb + Tc + Td + Te)
```

where epsilon is some small non-negative number (say 1e-5). Since CPLEX (or any solver) doesn't want to "pay the price" it will make each `Tx` variable (and therefore `T`) to be just as big as necessary. Tb would be 10, and not 1000 as in your original solution.

When reporting the optimal solution, just be sure to report the value of the variable `T`, and not the `Objective function` value.